# Blender UV Mapping Beveled Edge

Tags: uv, bevel

I'm not a modeler. I'm not an artist. I opened Blender for the first time a couple months ago and TBH I'm not enjoying it. I just need a few basic primitive shapes for a mod I am making and it is vexing me that 'simple' things take me days to figure out - if I can at all. Anyway, just letting you know that I'm a clueless nube. :)

I am making basic shapes in blender and using preexisting texture files. Cubes and wedges I managed to figure out, sort-of, but UV mapping curves are still no-go. Take a cube, bevel one vertical edge so you end up with a quarter-round shape and apply wood texture. The problem I have is getting that curved face to simply 'lay the image down' on it. I have clicked on every option in the UV menu, I have separated faces and meshes, I have marked all edges, no edges, random edges... this is a common task and I found numerous posts and videos, but I have not found one that actually answers this question for me.
The best results I get is by using 'smart uv project', but the vertical faces it generates are not contiguous.

How the heck do I get the UV texture to simply apply across the vertical faces- ignoring the lines for the bevel?

[image]

The image show the results of the Smart UV Project. It is almost good, but it is separating in the center of the curve rather than at the edges. Note the highlighted faces.

Comment: Hello could you please pack your image (File >External Data > Pack Resources) and share your file? Use this platform or another one: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: It's not a file specific thing. I literally just opened Blender 3.6.1, took the default Cube, changed the Dimensions box, applied all transforms, and used Bevel on an edge with 20 segments. Used UV mapping and loaded a Texture Image. Nothing else other than random experiments with Separating faces and the different UV unwrap options. The screenshot, that finally appeared, is a model I made in 3 minutes on-the-fly for this post.

Comment: I've also tried and couldn't meet the problem so it would help if you shared the file

Answer (score 1):

it's best to think in terms of loops or groups of faces you want together. for instance, you want to keep all the long faces of the mesh (the bevelled ones and the long cube faces) in one continuous block. as such, you only want to insert one seam in that loop (so that it can be unrolled like a yoga mat).
[image]

here's my example, the only seam edges are those around the top and bottom faces, and the single edge on the right hand side.

another thing to consider is using the right kind of uv unwrapping. if you're unwrapping for a pre-made texture like this (i.e. you care about where faces are relative to one another), you may want to avoid Smart UV Project. instead, continuing from the previous screenshot, i selected all and simply used 'Unwrap' from the UV menu.
[image]

as you can see, the faces are arranged continuously across the curve and around one side. the continuity is broken on the right side of the curve, since that's where we put the seam. if you can find a tiling wood texture and stretch the UV map (just scaling with S) to fill it side to side, you should be able to make it seamless.